# VBA - Check If String Sentence Contains ANY Word From List

Tags: vba, dictionary, match

**String Sentence**: "may have linked documents from another"

**Word Dictionary**: linked, may, from

**Pseudocode**:

```
If StringSentence containsAny(wordDictionary) Then
     MsgBox "contains a word"
Else
     MsgBox "doesn't containt any word from list"
End If
```

The comparison from word list to sentence should be case insensitive. I have tried creating an object with properties and using `exists` but I get false positives. Perhaps because of the word casing.

Comment: imo the best way to deal with *words* to avoid false substring matches and to deal with punctuation is a regex \b(linked|may|from)\b see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to split the wordDictionary and to search for every single one of the splited items. If even one is found the boolean `hasWord` is changed to `True`. Then, based on this boolean value, the correct `MsgBox` text is given:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim sentence        As String
    Dim wordDictonary   As String

    Dim myArray         As Variant
    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim hasWord         As Boolean

    sentence = "may have linked documents from another"
    wordDictonary = "linkeD, mAy, From "    
    sentence = LCase(sentence)
    wordDictonary = LCase(wordDictonary)        
    myArray = Split(wordDictonary, ",")

    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If InStr(1, sentence, Trim(myArray(cnt))) Then hasWord = True : Exit For
    Next cnt

    MsgBox (IIf(hasWord, "Contains a word", "Does not contain a word!"))

End Sub
```

To disregard big and small letters, the `sentence` and the `wordDictionary` variables are lowercased with `LCase`.

Comment: May as well `Exit For` if `hasWord` is `True`, speeds up execution if we don't care which word it contains

Comment: @Greedo - if the `OP` abuses the code so much that `Exit For` will noticeably speed up the execution, then he/she deserves a slow code. :) But in general, it is good to add it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Array` and make uses of the `Instr` function. How you create your array is up to you, but here's an example:

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim sArray() As Variant
  Dim sSentence As String
  Dim s As Variant
  Dim sDict as String
  sDict = "linked, may, from"

  sSentence = "may have linked documents from another"
  sArray = Split(sDict,",")

  For Each s In sArray
    If InStr(1, sSentence, Trim$(s), VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("'" & s & "' was found.")
    Else
      MsgBox ("'" & s & "' was NOT found.")
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need the status of the task for all words, not per word. E.g. `doesn't containt any word from list` or `contains a word`.